# Why can I no longer suggest edits?

Tags: support, editing

I have noticed recently, that both in meta, and in Skeptics Main, I no longer have the ability to suggest an edit.

[image: Why can't I edit?????]

Is this a site-wide thing, or is it just my account? Is there a reason this happened? Did I get edit-banned or something, or did SE decide that all users can no longer suggest edits?

---

Note: This is happening on **every question**, so I'm wondering if there is something really wrong with my account.

---

Edit: I realized that this must have happened recently, since I made an [edit](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/9015/revisions) only a few weeks before the time of this posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit suggestions are disabled on meta, but you should still be able to edit on the main site. The edit link is not visible if there is already a suggested edit pending on the post, so check if you don't see the edit link anywhere on the main site.

Comment: I can't edit _any_ of the questions (unless every single question on the front page has a pending suggested edit...)

Comment: @Ephraim Try it again, we had a huge number of tag wiki edits queued, they might have overwhelmed the edit queue and any further edit were probably blocked.

Comment: Yup, it works now! I guess that was the problem. Just out of curiosity though, was it just me that couldn't edit, or did this happen to everyone?

Comment: That was for anyone with less than 2k reputation.